# Django __str__ reduce SQL queries

Tags: python, sql, django, database-performance

I have two models in my Django project

```
class BookSerie(models.Model):
    id = models.AutoField(primary_key=True)
    title = models.CharField(max_length=255)

class BookVolume(models.Model):
    isbn = models.CharField(max_length=17)
    volumeNumber = models.PositiveIntegerField()
    serie = models.ForeignKey(BookSerie)

    def __str__(self):
        return self.serie.title+" volume "+str(self.volumeNumber)+" - "+str(self.isbn)
```

I only use  __ str __ for my admin panel but when I use this code in my view (serie with id=1 have 5 volumes) :

```
def serieDetails(request, title):
    try:
        seriequery = BookSerie.objects.get(slug=title)
        BookVolume.objects.filter(serie=seriequery).order_by('volumeNumber')
    except BookSerie.DoesNotExist:
        raise Http404("Serie does not exist")

    return render(request, 'book/serieDetails.html', {'serie': seriequery, 'volumes' : volumesquery})
```

I have an important issue :

Query SELECT ••• FROM "book_bookserie" WHERE "book_bookserie"."id" = '1' is performed 5 times (django debug toolbar give this code line   **return self.serie.title+" volume "+str(self.volumeNumber)+" - "+str(self.isbn)**

Query 
SELECT ••• FROM "book_bookvolume" WHERE "book_bookvolume"."serie_id" = '1' ORDER BY "book_bookvolume"."volumeNumber" ASC
is performed 2 times

Answer (score 2):

In your `BookVolume`'s `__str__` you access `self.serie.title`. This hits the database every time, as the according `BookSerie` record must be retrieved. One way to reduce queries here is to use [`select_related`](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/1.9/ref/models/querysets/#select-related) when you query your `BookVolume`:

```
# any reason why you don't store this QuerySet to a variable?
BookVolume.objects.filter(serie=seriequery).order_by('volumeNumber').select_related('serie')

# better:
seriequery.bookvolume_set.order_by('volumeNumber').select_related('serie')
```

From the docs:
`select_related`...

> ... will “follow” foreign-key relationships, selecting additional related-object data when it executes its query. This is a performance booster which results in a single more complex query but means later use of foreign-key relationships won’t require database queries.

Comment: Thank you ! 
You solved my problem with __ str __ but I still have some issues with the second query.